# Add action into artisan command

Tags: php, laravel

Can I add extra action or run something after eg. running the command `php artisan down`?

I want to do something else after I've ran that command.
Can I extend upon the existing `down()` command or I will need to write a new custom artisan command and run that instead and have that call `down()` command?

What I want to do here is push an event to third party API when the application is brought down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create your own artisan command. 
Inside that command do this:

```
$this->call('down');
```

Why?

1. The down command does exactly what everybody expects it to do.
2. You have your own command with the business logic.

If you at one point want do do something else with `artisan down` you can simply create another command.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for clearing up my mind.